# jquery array to object returns empty

Tags: jquery

I have an array like so `['ABC123', 'ABC124']` and I am trying to put these items into an object so I can add more items:

```
var editObject = {};

        $.each(editHolder, function () {
            editObject[editHolder] = $('#' + editHolder).text();
        });

        console.log(editObject);
```

but this returns `Object {ABC123,ABC124: ""}`

what I am expecting is `{ABC123: "text", ABC124: "text2"}`

`$('#' + editHolder).text();` is suppose to be the text in an input text feild with that id (which does exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide variables to your function and use them instead of full object:

```
var editObject = {};

$.each(editHolder, function (index, value) {
    editObject[value] = $('#' + value).text();
});

console.log(editObject);
```

Here you can read more information [about jQuery.each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)